# Angular Fire Store - Error "No Properties in common with type 'GetOptions'."

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to get one value from a document. I tried the following:

```
getAuthorData(){
const test = this.afs.collection('Authors').doc('Test').get('name');
console.log(test);
}
```

Unfortunately i'm receiving the following error:

> ERROR in src/app/blogdetail/blogdetail.component.ts(55,65): error TS2559: Type '"name"' has no properties in common with type 'GetOptions'.

Answer (score 0):

Based on these docs -> https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md

You are going to need to call something like

```
const test = this.afs.doc('Authors/Test').valueChanges();
```

Then in your html you need to use the async pipe like

```
{{ (item | async)?.name }}
```

If you don't want to use pipe you can .subscribe to the valueChanges observable. Like..

```
this.afs.doc('Authors/Test').valueChanges().subscribe(doc => {
    this.name = doc.name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not giving getOptions to the get method:
you have to give a getOptions object as it is explained here https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.GetOptions.

```
var getOptions = {
source: 'cache'
};
```

But I don't think that will solve your problem, I imagine you want to get the value of name from a document. Then you should try something like:

```
this.afs.doc('Authors/'Test').get().then(object =>{
  test = object.get("name");
});
```

You can checkout the documentation here! https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data